# Python Selenium Webdriver Select Dropdown Value

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate the search process in this website: https://www.bcbsga.com/health-insurance/provider-directory/searchcriteria
The process involves clicking on the "Continue" button to search under the 'guest' mode. The next page has got a list of drop-down items to refine the search criteria. My code either produces the "Element not visible" exception (which I corrected by using a wait) or times out. Please help.

Here's my code:

```
# navigate to the desired page
driver.get("https://www.bcbsga.com/health-insurance/provider-directory/searchcriteria")
# get the guest button
btnGuest = driver.find_element_by_id("btnGuestContinue")
#click the guest button
btnGuest.click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
#Find a Doctor Search Criteria page
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_PFPlanQuestionnaire_ddlQuestionnaireInsurance")))
lstGetInsurance = Select(element)
lstGetInsurance.select_by_value("BuyMyself$14States")

# close the browser window
#driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use input search and key.return:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

divID = 'ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_PFPlanQuestionnaire_ddlQuestionnaireInsurance_chosen'
inputID = 'ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_PFPlanQuestionnaire_ddlQuestionnaireInsurance_chosen_input'
inputValue = 'I buy it myself (or plan to buy it myself)'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.bcbsga.com/health-insurance/provider-directory/searchcriteria")
driver.find_element_by_id("btnGuestContinue").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_id(divID).click()
driver.find_element_by_id(inputID).send_keys(inputValue)
driver.find_element_by_id(inputID).send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(6)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks much for your solution - it works! I wonder what is wrong with my earlier code. Any pointers? I'd tried even selecting by visible text.

Comment: Id you use is 'select' id but choice is stored in 'input' type text appears when you are chosen.